# Angular 6 router-outlet styling applied to element below it

Tags: html, angular, sass, angular-animations

I'm in a phase of adding router transitions to the angular application and I'm facing weird problem. Styling for `router-outlet` gets applied to the element below it in the DOM hierarchy.

Here's my code:

```
<main role="main">
  <!-- Header -->
  <app-header class="topnavbar-wrapper"></app-header>
  <!-- Page content-->
  <div [@fadeAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</main>
```

Styling:

```
main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 4.5rem;
  min-height: 92vh;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
  /* Height of footer */
  position: relative;
}
router-outlet ~ * {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: $secondary;
}
```

Animations work smoothly, I have no problem with that. But the router-outlet styling is applied to element below it and this makes footer fixed at the bottom, overlaying the content. If I clear styling of router-outlet element then animation won't work correctly.

[image: This happens]

As you can see on the screen `<app-overview>` element has `router-outlet` styling which is what causes the problem. I guess that solution lies in correct **scss** styling but so far I wasn't able to figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selector `router-outlet ~ *` selects all of the `router-outlet` siblings, that's why it applies on `app-overview`.

Also you shouldn't try to style a `router-outlet` since it is not rendered (it's just a placeholder)

Comment: What's the workaround for this? If router-outlet is not styled, I can see the deactivated route component being shifted down before disappearing

Comment: @dallows I answered the primary question "Why router-outlet styling is applied to element below it", but the final purpose is still unclear. Maybe post more code or even a StackBlitz to clarify

Comment: Makes sense, It answers my question.

Comment: How did you do this? Could you fix the footer?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on an Ionic Project which primarily uses Angular, I wanted to style router outlet to follow my CSS grids applied, `ion-router-outlet` didn't work out, so I used `router-outlet` and it worked fine. Related to the question but not that specific, might help someone out there.